# Splitting Display into 3 or 4 equal columns

Tags: php

I'm using PHP and MySQL to display a list of about a thousand names in a single column.

Is there a way to modify the code so that the data is displayed in more than one column, preferably of equal height? In this particular example, either three or four columns would probably work.

This is my code...

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT P.URL, P.Title, P.Site, P.Live,
 PB.Common, PB.First, PB.Middle, PB.Last, PB.Prefix, PB.Suffix, PB.Alpha, PB.Born, PB.Died,     PB.Birth_Place, PB.Death_Place, PB.Nationality, ART.URL, ART.Site, ART.Brief, ART.Article
 FROM people P
 LEFT JOIN people_1_bio PB ON PB.URL = P.URL
 LEFT JOIN people_articles ART ON ART.URL = P.URL
 WHERE P.Site = 'PX' AND ART.Site = 'PX' AND ART.Brief !='' AND P.Live = 1
 GROUP BY P.URL ORDER BY P.N");
 $stm->execute(array(
));

while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $URL = $row['URL'];
 $Common = $row['Common'];
 $Article = $row['ART'];
 $Common = $row['Common'];
 $Alpha = $row['Alpha'];
 $Site[] = $row['Site'];
 $List[] = '<a href="#'.$URL.'">'.$row['Common'].'</a>';

 $Roster[] = '<a href="/People/'.$URL.'">'.$Common.'</a><br>';
}

echo '<div style="width: 200px; font-size: 75%; text-align: left; float: left; margin-right:    15px;">';
echo join( $Roster, '' );
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to display your information in more columns.

Comment: So this isn't really anything to do with MySQL is it?

Comment: I'm using PHP and MySQL; I would guess the solution would involve PHP more than MySQL, but I really don't know; I just thought it would help to mention the programs I'm working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just use [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) like this. The following example breaks the array `$Roster` up in to 3 chunks:

```
// Set how many chunks you want to break the array into.
$how_many_chunks = 3;

// Break the '$Roster' array into '$roster_chunks'
$roster_chunks = array_chunk($Roster, $how_many_chunks, true);

// Roll through the '$roster_chunks'
foreach ($roster_chunks as $roster_chunk_key => $roster_chunk_value) {
  echo '<div style="width: 200px; font-size: 75%; text-align: left; float: left; margin-right: 15px;">';
  echo join($roster_chunk_value, '' );
  echo '</div>';
}
```

You can—of course—set some logic to determine how many chunks you want to break things up into. But your question & query doesn’t make that clear. It basically comes down to your personal desires & requirements.

Comment: That array_chunk script works pretty nice, except the alphabetical order is kind of strange. For example, the first column starts with Edward Abbey and ends with Henry Wallace, while the second column starts with John Quincy Adams and ends with William Wallace. It would be nice if the first column simply started with the first value, ran consecutively (ending with Alan Bateman, for example), with the second column then starting where the first column left off. I thought my ORDER BY clause would do that, but I was wrong. Awesome script, though...