# What's wrong with my array_chunk?

Tags: php

Someone showed me how to use PHP's array_chunk feature @ [Splitting Display into 3 or 4 equal columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832200/splitting-display-into-3-or-4-equal-columns) The general consensus was that my question was answered, and the problems I was still having had something to do with my database or code. I wasn't sure if I should ask another question there or start a new thread.

Anyway, I continued working on my code and have actually made some small improvements, but the main problems are still there: 1) I can't control the number of columns that display; if I set the value at 2, it will display four columns; 2) it alphabetizes the data HORIZONTALLY. For example, the first word in each column ends with an A (e.g. Adams, Akron, Ammon and Azazi), and the last word in each column ends with W.

I'd like to alphabetize the first column FIRST; if the last word in that column is Bruin, then the first word in the second column should be whatever comes next (e.g. Cato). And if the last word in the second column is Marsh, then the first word in the third column might be Marto. In other words, it flows from top to bottom, one column at a time.

I pasted my query into phpMyAdmin > SQL and it displays perfectly. I also echoed this...

```
echo join($List)
```

above the foreach statement, and it displays a single column in alphabetical order.

So my best guess is that the problem is in one of these two lines of code:

```
$roster_chunks = array_chunk($List, $how_many_chunks, true);

foreach ($roster_chunks as $roster_chunk_key => $roster_chunk_value)
```

Can anyone see what I did wrong? I posted the entire code below.

---

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT P.N, P.URL, P.Title, P.Site, P.Live,
 PB.Common, ART.URL, ART.Site, ART.Brief, ART.Article
 FROM people P
 LEFT JOIN people_bios PB ON PB.URL = P.URL
 LEFT JOIN people_articles ART ON ART.URL = P.URL
 WHERE P.Site = 'PX' AND ART.Site = 'PX' AND ART.Brief !='' AND P.Live = 1
 ORDER BY P.N");
 $stm->execute(array(
));

while ($row = $stm->fetch()) {
   $URL = $row['URL'];
   $Common = $row['Common'];

   $List[] = '<a href="/People/'.$URL.'">'.$Common.'</a><br>';
}

// Set how many chunks you want to break the array into.
$how_many_chunks = 3;

// Break the '$Roster' array into '$roster_chunks'
$roster_chunks = array_chunk($List, $how_many_chunks, true);

// Roll through the '$roster_chunks'
foreach ($roster_chunks as $roster_chunk_key => $roster_chunk_value) {
    echo '<div style="width: 175px; font-size: 75%; text-align: left; float: left; margin-right: 15px;">';
    echo join($roster_chunk_value);
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, `array_chunk()` is not for you.

`array_chunk()` will give you

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

While  you want

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

You need to make a custom function that will split your array into arrays in this way. `array_chunk()` will not help you if that's how you want to order it.

Comment: I see. In that case, rather than get in even deeper over my head trying to figure out a custom function, I should probably just stick with array_chunk then. Can anyone tell me how to make it display the number of columns I tell it to, rather than displaying 4 columns when I tell it to display 2?

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom: Well, in your code, you have `$how_many_chunks`. Now I may not be the best expert around, but I think that'll do what you want it to :P